# HikariCP - no suitable driver error

Tags: hikaricp

I tried switching to **Hikari-CP** for `java 1.6/1.7` but i m getting the below error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.<init>(DriverDataSource.java:52) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.3.5.jar:na]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

I m using Oracle DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sounds like the driver jar is not visible in the classpath, or the driver is not a self-registering driver.  What database are you using?  Please add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 5):

This line from documentation was the reason.

When using this property with "old" drivers, you may also need to set the driverClassName property, but try it first without.

The minute i did setup the driverClassName explicitly it started working.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.  I'll make that text bold on the project page.

Comment: I had this same issue. Weird thing is my code works fine in eclipse, but fails as a tomcat webapp. Calling HikariConfig.setDriverClassName() made it work in all situations

Answer (score 4):

- **make sure that expected `JdbcDriver` is available**

If you are running a `jar` artifact you can verify with following command in Linux/MacOS, (example shows [mysql jdbc Driver](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html))

```
$ jar -tvf your-lovely.jar  | grep "com/mysql/cj/jdbc/Driver"
   733 Sun Mar 25 07:00:36 PDT 2018 com/mysql/cj/jdbc/Driver.class
```

- **If `JdbcDriver` is available and you still get `No suitable driver` error, register the `JdbcDriver`.**

Example using [HicariConfig#setDriverClassName](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java#L470),

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class ConnectionPool {

    private HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(getConfig());

    private HikariConfig getConfig() {

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lovely_database_name");
        config.setUsername("root");
        config.setPassword("root");
        config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); //alternative is Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")

        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");

        return config;
    }

    Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you sure that driver jar and other dependencies are in place and just you have received this error then try to build a connection by this manner.

```
config.setJdbcUrl(JDBC_URL);
config.setUsername(JDBC_USERNAME);
config.setPassword(JDBC_PASSWORD);
config.setDriverClassName(JDBC_DRIVERCLASSNAME);
```

HikariCp looks these properties like this.

If you try to ser the drriver clss via property it won't work and you will receive the error related to driver.

```
props.addDataSourceProperty("dataSourceClassName", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```